# Solving the differential equation: $y' = y^2 +1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solving the differential equation: $y' = y^2 +1$, given $y(0)=1$

What I did initially was to Integrate $y^2 + 1$, then I realised that $y$ is not the variable of the integration.

I then grouped $y^2 - y' = 1$ and then this equation don't make sense to me so, I went to look at the answer key.

It states: Since $y^2 + 1> 1$, then $\int \frac{1}{y^2+1} y' =1$ This way we can get a function that is in the form of $y = x$.

But I do not still understand the reason of the answer key's method. Why did they say $y^2 + 1> 1$ ? and I know it has probably has got to do something with $y(0)=1$, but I don't know the reason.

I just started to study differential equations

Comment: This is a prime example of a differential equation that can be solved using the [Fourier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).

Comment: $y^2+1 > 1$ is important because that means it's bounded away from zero, and thus $1/(y^2+1)$ never blows up from the denominator approaching zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can solve this differential equation using the Fourier method. It is important that:

$$ \forall y \in \mathbb{R} : \ y^2+1 \neq 0. $$

Hence, we can divide $y'$ by this expression and get the following:

$$ \frac{ y' (x) }{ y(x)^2+1 } = 1 . $$

Then we can integrate both sides of the last equation with respect to $x$. We obtain:

$$ \arctan (y(x)) = x + C \Rightarrow y(x) = \tan ( x+ C). $$

Since we need to obey $y(0) = 1$, we must solve:

$$ y(0) = \tan (0+C) = 1. $$

We obtain the solution as:

$$C = \pi \bigg( n + \frac{1}{4} \bigg), \ n \in \mathbb{Z} .$$